# Form submitting/inserting data to mySQL database on page load

Tags: php, forms

I am having an issue with one of my .php pages.

adddata.php has a form which allows a user to submit certain data to the database however each time the page loads or is refreshed, the empty form is submitted (creating a row of blank values in the DB).

I have little experience with PHP so apologies in advance for any novice mistakes - here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Project IPAM - Add Data</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" class="container" style="width:980px">


<?php

include('./templates/header.php'); 
include('./templates/dbconnect.php');


?>



<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['address_v4'];
    echo "Successful submitted";

}
?>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#ABCDEF;height:500px;width:980px">

<!--  This is a example submit form to add data to the database !-->



<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form method="post" action="adddata.php">
<table width="" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Insert Data Into mySQL Database </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>IP(v4)</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="address_v4" type="text" id="address_v4" maxlength="15"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hostname</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="hostname" type="text" id="hostname" maxlength="32"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Type</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><select name="type">
<option value="static">Static</option>
<option value="dhcp">DHCP</option>
<option value="reserved">Reserved</option>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Updated By</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="updated_by" type="text" id="updated_by" maxlength="16"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Notes</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="notes" type="text" id="notes" maxlength="128"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Location</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea cols="17" rows="7" name="location" type="text" id="location" maxlength="64"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Default Gateway</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="default_gateway" type="text" id="default_gateway" maxlength="15"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Subnet Mask</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="subnet_mask" type="text" id="subnet_mask" maxlength="15"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


<?php


// Connect to the DB
include_once('./templates/dbconnect.php');

// Get values from form and checks whether values have been initilized using the isset() function.
$address=isset($_POST['address_v4']);
$hostname=isset($_POST['hostname']);
$type=isset($_POST['type']);
$updated_by=isset($_POST['updated_by']);
$notes=isset($_POST['notes']);
$location=isset($_POST['location']);
$default_gateway=isset($_POST['default_gateway']);
$subnet_mask=isset($_POST['subnet_mask']);



// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(address_v4, hostname, type, updated_by, notes, location, default_gateway, subnet_mask)
        VALUES('$address','$hostname','$type','$updated_by','$notes','$location','$default_gateway','$subnet_mask')";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))//
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }


mysql_close($con)
?>








</div>
<div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">
Copyright © 2011 Richard Day
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider using a PHP MVC framework instead of writing spaghetti code, since it will make your life a whole lot easier in the long run. Examples of PHP MVC frameworks: [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/), [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), [Cake PHP](http://cakephp.org/) and many others.

Comment: Also, prefer [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) instead of the `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is where you're checking is your $_POST variables are set, eg.:

```
$address=isset($_POST['address_v4']);
```

`isset` returns a boolean (true or false) value, not the data that's in the variable you're checking against. Change you're lines to something like this:

```
$address=isset($_POST['address_v4']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address_v4']) : '';
```

`mysql_real_escape_string` will help prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks being carried out against your website.

EDIT

If I understand you right you also need to check to see if a form has actually been submitted before running your database statement, at the moment you're running it regardless of whether or not the form has been submitted. Move all of your PHP code from the bottom of the document inside the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` statement at the top, that should sort it out.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name = $_POST['address_v4'];
  echo "Successful submitted";

  // Now the code from the bottom, minus the database file include as you've already got that further up in the code
  $address=isset($_POST['address_v4']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address_v4']) : '';

  // ...
```

Comment: Hi Clive - thanks for your response. I've changed the lines to what you suggested however its still submitting blank data on page load. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I've moved the code from the bottom into the isset() statement as per your comment - the form is no longer submitting on page load, however it no longer submits when I enter data in the form normally

Comment: Have got it working now - had missed out "mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());" and looks like its working :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) checks if a value is set or not and returns `true` or `false`. Change that to something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['address_v4']))
{
    // if the value does indeed exist, then prepare it to be used in an SQL query
    // and assign it to the $address variable
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address_v4']);
}
else
{
    // if the value does not exist, then make the $address variable an
    // empty string
    $address = '';
}
```

Same for the rest of the variables you need to add in the query.

Comment: Hi Radu, thanks very much for your input. I've tried this method as well as Clive's and neither seem to be stopping the form from submitting the blank data. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: $tbl_name = "addresses"; and the name of the file is adddata.php

Answer (score 0):

First of you need to verify your input.

Use `isset();` to verify if they're set, use `empty();` to check whether the variables are empty. Use the `&&` operator to perform multiple checks at once.

Cast the variables to their appropriate data types. Escape your input with `mysql_real_escape_string();` before storing into your database.

Use the [post-redirect-get](http://www.google.com.ng/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=post%20redirect%20get) method to prevent form submission on refresh or reload.